# How can I create an artificial corrupted desert biome?

Tags: terraria

To craft the [Dao of Pow](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dao_of_Pow), a dark and light shard is required from a dark and light mummy, which spawns on corrupted and hallowed deserts respectively. Unfortunately it seems that in my world there are only natural hallowed deserts, which means that I've only managed to obtain light shards.

The [Terraria Wiki article for mummies](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mummy) indicates that it is relatively easy to create the biome artificially, but lacks any significant details on how to do so. I've experimented myself with small amounts of ebonsand quarantined in forest biomes, but so far no dark mummies have spawned. What is the minimum amount of ebonsand needed for dark mummies to spawn, and how can I do this without corrupting a normal desert?

Answer (score 4):

Dark Mummies spawn on Ebonsand blocks in the Corruption, and that's about it.

What I did was build a long strip of Ebonsand in the sky, and then I ran back and forth with a Battle Potion active. You can also coat an area in the Corruption with a 1-block layer of Ebonsand so that every monster spawn has a chance to be a Dark Mummy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to farm some corrupted ebon stone from the underground hard mode corruption biome.  I'm pretty sure one brick will do it, though more might speed up the process.  Anyway, go place the brick or bricks in the desert.  Just make sure they are touching the sand.  Eventually the corruption will spread into the desert, and you have your corrupted biome.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I would like to avoid corrupting a normal desert because that will require partioning off the entire desert just to make the farm

Comment: @YiJang it isn't possible to create a desert biome AFAIK unless you drain an ocean.  If you need a desert for water leaf farming (or something else entirely), I would suggest starting a new world and using that desert to do whatdver you need, and then going ahead and creating a corrupted desert in your hard more world.  I always have backup normal-mode worlds available now for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Steampunker living in one of your houses, then, buy a clentaminator from her. During a blood moon, she will sell purple solution for the clentaminator. Buy it and spray it where you want, and it will create corruption wherever you spray it.

Comment: But, he doesn't want to put a normal desert on a corrupted state.

Comment: He doesn't need to, he can put it on a floating island, he can do it wherever he wants., Also, even if he did corrupt a normal desert, after getting what he wants, he could very easily and quickly decorrupt it with green solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Gray Bricks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gray_Brick) or any blocks that prevent corruption spreading but gray bricks are easy to get. It will prevent spread of the corruption you made build an elevated platform(multiple layers if you want to farm faster) and lay sand and the bricks. If you already have ebonsand, place that directly or slot [ebonstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ebonstone_Block) between the sand blocks to corrupt the sand. Note that corruption spreads so if you place [ebonstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ebonstone_Block) sparsely it might take awhile before it becomes a biome.

Note that to let the game consider the area you build a biome. There must be 50 tiles of the biome block which in this case ebonsand. Note that [ebonstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ebonstone_Block) does not count into the corrupted desert biome as it is considered [corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption).

In the case where there is another more dominant biome already present, the background and lighting will stay as the original but no worries, mummies will still spawn - Just at a lesser rate since there are more variants of monster from the original biome that will also spawn. So I suggest you build it in a originally forest biome..

Answer (score -2):

I just drained the ocean on an extra hardmode world I didn't play on.then I placed ebon stone on the ocean floor.bota bing botta bam there is a corupt desert.

Answer (score -2):

Holy water, on sand, easy. just make it 2-3 layers

Comment: Holy water is for making hallowed biome. You probably meant the other kind of water.

Comment: In addition to being backwards, we prefer to have more detailed answers rather than basic one-liners whenever possible. Perhaps consider adding some more detail to your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Hmm? Oh just take rope, go above 'bout 50-100 blocks, (so no wyverns)

Take *at least* 300 ebonsand/sand and some gray bricks (to put on the bottom so it doesn't all fall) and make a long bridge drink a battle potion and run around!

I prefer making an AFK volcano trap and just wait you'll collect tons of money and drops!! All on an artificial floating desert of evil!